# MySQL select from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables witch bunch of fields [only needed mentioned]

```
 - partners
  - id [PRI, int]
  - name [varchar(20)]
  - match [=matches.id]
  - can_call [int]  


 - players
  - registered [0/1]
  - partner [=partners.id]
  - match [=matches.id]
```

Now, I need one query, that will give one `int` – how many players can one of partners call;

To get how many players any partner called for any match, I use:

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM players
WHERE registered=1
  AND partner=PARTNER_ID
  AND match=MATCH_ID
```

Now, I need to have something like this:

```
SELECT (can_call-THE_ABOVE) as free
FROM partners
WHERE match=MATCH_ID
```

And I don't know how to do it :)

The idea is: get free positions for partner we want for the match we want, then substract SELECT COUNT(id) players, that have already been registered for that match by that partner.

Thank you! [I hope I make sense ^_^]

**EDIT**: I already solved (before the two join answers). I'll probably go with my solution, just because it's simpler; but I will look more into the other answers once I'll want to become MySQL advnaced user, thanks everyone ^^

Comment: What is your "TOTAL" from...  Is it a fixed "maximum team size" or something?

Comment: @Ashwini: because real beginner in terms of MySQL, so joins makes as much sense as what I though I'll use. @DRapp – My mistake, totall is actually 'can_call', will replace it in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, figured it out; it's exactly as my pseudocode above:

```
SELECT can_call - (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM players WHERE ...) as free
  WHERE match=MATCH_ID AND id=PARTNER_ID
```

^^

Answer (score 2):

```
Select P.name
    , P.can_call - Coalesce(Calls.CallCount,0) As CanCall
From partners As P
    Left Join   (
                Select partner, match, Count(*) As CallCount
                From players As P1
                Where registered = 1
                Group By partner, match, 
                ) As Calls
        On Calls.partner = P.id
            And Calls.match = P.match
Where P.match = MATCH_ID
```

Comment: That looks genuinely hardcore... I might use that as reply why I'm not considering `JOIN`... Thank you though! :)

Comment: I think you should intercgange the two `FROM...` clauses

Comment: @yypercube - Yes. That's a mental typo on my part.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT pa.can_call-COUNT(pl.id)
       AS free
FROM partners pa
  LEFT JOIN players pl
    ON pl.registered=1
      AND pl.partner=pa.id
      AND pl.match=pa.match
WHERE pa.id=PARTNER_ID
  AND pa.match=MATCH_ID
GROUP BY pa.id
       , pa.match
```

Comment: The `GROUP BY` can be dropped, I think.

Comment: @Adam: You may use this as an excuse when you do start considering JOINs.